# SQL - How can I insert into a table based on a condition?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables - An orders table and an inventory table. The inventory table keeps track of the product_id, the product_type and the amount of remaining stock. While the orders table keeps track of the order_id, product_id and order_amount. The orders table is joined to the inventory table by product_id.

What is the best way to ensure that I never have an order that comes in which has an order amount > remaining stock for a particular product_id?

It does not seem like I can use an `INSERT INTO` with a `WHERE` - wherein I only add orders to the orders table when the order amount < remaining stock amount. Is there another way? Im willing to change the way my tables are set up.

Comment: How do you update the inventory when you get a new order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add a trigger on the orders table. That trigger would subtract `order_amount` from the amount of remaining stock. That would automate the calculation of the remaining stock.

Additionally, I would add a check on the remaining stock value to be `>= 0`. This way you will block an order that would excess remaining stock. The insertion would be rolled-back because it would violate the stock check.

---

```
CREATE FUNCTION update_inventory_amount()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
BEGIN
    IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
        UPDATE
            inventory
        SET
            amount = amount - NEW.order_amount
        WHERE
            product_id = NEW.product_id;
    END IF;

    RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;

CREATE TRIGGER update_inventory_amount_trigger
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON orders
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_inventory_amount();

ALTER TABLE inventory ADD CONSTRAINT amount_check CHECK (amount >= 0);
```

The above trigger code is just for `UPDATE`. With a little effort you can extend it to also cover `UPDATE` and `DELETE`.

Comment: Where can I add this check on the remaining stock value? Everytime I UPDATE the orders table?

Comment: Just once: `ALTER TABLE inventory ADD CONSTRAINT amount_check CHECK (amount > 0);` It will be checked every time the `amount` changes.

Comment: @walksignison - See my updated answer. I've added example code.

Comment: Why do we update after the INSERT and not before it? Also, shouldn't the trigger be tied to when we are inserting a new order? And if that were the case, how would I reference the instrument_id the order is for in order to update the stock in inventory?

Comment: @walksignison You're right, sorry - it was just quick copy-paste and I forgot to alter the code. With `NEW` you can access all fields from the inserted `orders` row.

Comment: One last thing.. Why do we require the ```IF TG_OP``` statement - isn't the trigger connected to this function already based on an INSERT? And is it okay if I have a ```ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION``` in my orders table, while making use of this trigger?

Comment: @walksignison If you are absolutely sure that there will be only `INSERT` operations then, indeed, you can remove the `TG_OP` condition. Otherwise I suggest to cover all possible operations on the `orders` table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178519/discussion-between-walksignison-and-adam).